# Distinct List from nonlinear Excel Range C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, office-interop

I'm having issues with the below. The first bit of code works by pulling in all distinct values into a list-box for the user to review. However, when the data is filtered, it still pulls in all the hidden values which is not what I want. When I tried to only pull visible cells into the range, it broke the conversion of my range to a distinct list. Any thoughts on why breaking the range up breaks this? Code breaks on System.Array myvalues line with error "Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'System.Array'". Seems odd to me.

Working Code:

```
Range values = sht.Range[cell1, cell2];
System.Array myvalues = (System.Array)values.Cells.Value;
string[] listValues = myvalues.OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
string[] listValues2 = listValues.Distinct().ToArray();
```

Breaking Code:

```
Range values = sht.Range[cell1, cell2].SpecialCells(XlCellType.xlCellTypeVisible);
System.Array myvalues = (System.Array)values.Cells.Value;
string[] listValues = myvalues.OfType<object>().Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray();
string[] listValues2 = listValues.Distinct().ToArray();
```

EDIT:

Working Code to handle when range is hidden and when it isn't:

```
var extractedFromSheet = new List<object>();
            foreach (Range area in values.Areas)
            {
                var areaValue = area.Value;
                if (areaValue is Array) // The area contains multiple cells
                {
                    var arr = (Array)areaValue;
                    extractedFromSheet.AddRange(arr.OfType<object>().Select(o => o .ToString()));
                }
                else // The area contains one cell
                {
                    extractedFromSheet.Add(areaValue);
                }
            }
            var distinct = extractedFromSheet.Distinct();
```

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. What I see is that the range is divided into `Areas` when some parts of range are hidden by filter. But this doesn't lead to error, but the `Value` just returns the first `Area`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xlCellTypeVisible` returns a non-contiguous `Range`. That range has an `.Areas` property, each of which is also a `Range`. Try iterating through `values.Areas` and getting the values from each of those ranges.

You'll also need to check each of those values because it could be single value or an array depending on whether the area contains one cell or multiple cells. That's probably the error you're seeing. It's reading a single string from one cell so it's not returning an array.

This should do it or be close:

```
var extractedFromSheet = new List<object>();
foreach(Range area in values.Areas)
{
    var areaValue = area.Value;
    if(areaValue is Array) // The area contains multiple cells
    {
        extractedFromSheet.AddRange((System.Array)areaValue);
    }
    else // The area contains one cell
    {
        extractedFromSheet.AddRange(areaValue);
    }
}
var distinct = extractedFromSheet.Distinct();
```

It's a little messed up that a property can return any type of object or an array. I don't even remember all of the stuff you have to do to make sure references to COM objects get cleaned up.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.areas.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I actually did not know about the .Areas property. Will give this a try today.

Comment: Me either, and I worked with Excel for a while. It's confusing because it breaks/ignores all the principles of OOP. A `Range` should behave like a `Range` which behaves like a `Range`. But instead knowing that you have a `Range` doesn't tell you how it behaves.

Comment: So I had to change your If statement to the following to get it to work across all scenarios. this is such a weird way for these objects to behave.

    if (areaValue is Array) // The area contains multiple cells
                    {
                        var arr = (Array)areaValue;
                        extractedFromSheet.AddRange(arr.OfType<object>().Select(o => o .ToString()));
                    }
                    else // The area contains one cell
                    {
                        extractedFromSheet.Add(areaValue);
                    }